# iterate array using map and display state and checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to lean react by solving a problem in react. Providing the react code challenge below.
I am trying to iterate the array and trying to print state and checkbox.

I googled but still no luck, not sure how to solve it. Providing my code below and stackblitz. Can you guys help me.

Type 'void[]' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-ngl4yu?description=React%20%20%20TypeScript%20starter%20project&file=src%2Fcomponents%2FstateDropdown.css,src%2Fcomponents%2FStateDropdown.tsx,src%2FApp.tsx,src%2Fcomponents%2FStates.tsx&title=React%20Starter

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import './stateDropdown.css';
import { states } from './States';
export function StateDropdown() {
  const [isDropDownDisplayed, setIsDropdowndisplayed] = useState(false);
  return (
    <fieldset className="state-dropdown">
      <button
        className=""
        onClick={() => setIsDropdowndisplayed((prevState) => !prevState)}
      >
        -- Select your states --
      </button>
      {isDropDownDisplayed && (
        <div className="panel">
          {states.map((state) => {
            <>
              <input type="checkbox" />
              <label>{state.name}</label>
            </>;
          })}
        </div>
      )}
    </fieldset>
  );
}
```

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V2zEAXLQbF4&t=794s

Comment: You need to add `return` in the callback function of `.map` to return the JSX.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is incorrect here, `map` should simply return your component like:

```
 {states.map((state) => (
   <>
     <input type="checkbox" />
     <label>{state.name}</label>
   </>
 ))}
```

I would also recommended applying the necessary `key` property to your fragment to ensure that all children in a list have a unique identifier for re-rendering.

```
 {states.map((state) => (
   <React.Fragment key={state.name}>
     <input type="checkbox" />
     <label>{state.name}</label>
   </React.Fragment>
 ))}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let aFunction = ()=> <span>Hi</span>;
```

Is a function that returns `<span>Hi</span>;`

```js
let aFunction = ()=>(<span>Hi</span>);
```

is also a function that returns `<span>Hi</span>;`

```js
let aFunction = ()=>{
  return <span>Hi</span>;
}
```

is also a function that returns `<span>Hi</span>;`

```js
let aFunction = ()=>{
 <span>Hi</span>;
}
```

Is a function that returns NOTHING

Answer (score 0):

zi.
Maybe you can update your code like this.

```
import { useState, Fragment } from "react";
import "./stateDropdown.css";
import { states } from "./States";

const StateDropdown = () => {
    const [isDropDownDisplayed, setIsDropdowndisplayed] = useState(false);
    return (
        <fieldset className="state-dropdown">
            <button
                onClick={() => setIsDropdowndisplayed(!isDropDownDisplayed)}
            >
                -- Select your states --
            </button>
            {isDropDownDisplayed && (
                <div className="panel">
                    {states.map((state, index) => (
                        <Fragment key={index}>
                            <input type="checkbox" />
                            <label>{state.name}</label>
                        </Fragment>
                    ))}
                </div>
            )}
        </fieldset>
    );
};

export default StateDropdown;
```

Good luck.